# Comparing two lists and printing the list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `Z1` and `Z2`. I am comparing these two lists and if at least one sublist of `Z1` appears in `Z2`, I want to print full `Z1`. I present the current and expected output.

```
Z1=[[0, 4], [0, 5], [4, 5]]
Z2=[[6, 5], [4, 9], [4, 8], [5, 3], [0,4]]

for i in range(0,len(Z1)):
    if (Z1[i]==Z2[i]):
        print("Z1 =",Z1)
```

The current output is

```
(Blank)
```

The expected output is

```
Z1=[[0, 4], [0, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: You're showing a high insistence with those 2 lists )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An rather elegant solution can be using sets and their intersection:

```
Z1=[[0, 4], [0, 5], [4, 5]]
Z2=[[6, 5], [4, 9], [4, 8], [5, 3], [0,4]]

zs1 = set(map(tuple, Z1))
zs2 = set(map(tuple, Z2))

if (zs1 & zs2):
    print("Z1 =",Z1)
```

Comment: better than brute force! O(1) but memory O(n). Best if lists small.

Comment: Nice use of *set* intersection here. +1

Answer (score 3):

You are not looking over all of `Z2` at most you arrive at `i=2` so you never arrive at the last item in `Z2` which is the one you are looking for (which should be `i=4`, but `len(Z1) < 4`).

Just loop over both, brute force solution:

```
>>> for z1 in Z1:
...     for z2 in Z2:
...             if z1 == z2:
...                     print("Z1 =",Z1)
...                     break
... 
Z1 = [[0, 4], [0, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: `if z1 in Z2:` would shorten up the code a bit rather than the nested `for`.

Comment: yes, just trying to show where the issue is in the code, thanks @JonSG

Comment: You might add in a version that used `any` just to show it as an alternative. Perhaps something like `Z3 = Z1 if any(i1 for i1 in Z1 if i1 in Z2) else []`

Answer (score 0):

Sets are faster (see Michael's answer) but the any() function with a comprehension can check the condition in a simple (albeit naive) way:

```
if any(z in Z1 for z in Z2): 
    print("Z1 =",Z1)
```

You could also benefit from set performance by converting Z1 to a set beforehand.  Any() will stop iterating as soon as a match is found so your process will not always convert all Z2 values to tuples (when there is a match).

```
S1 = set(map(tuple,Z1)) 
if any(tuple(z) in S1 for z in Z2): 
    print("Z1 =",Z1)
```

With a set, the disjoint method can perform the same thing as any() but with an inverse condition:

```
S1 = set(map(tuple,Z1)) 
if not S1.isdisjoint(map(tuple,Z2)): 
    print("Z1 =",Z1)
```